# How on the web or on this exchange can one find homemade / modified / custom wilderness technology?

Tags: discussion

Looking for websites, exchanges etc where people who have created or substantially modified outdoor technology for their own purposes share it, preferably in enough detail to allow others to comment on its safety and function and ideally create it for themselves.  Is there a way to pose or tag questions on outdoors.stackexchange to facilitate this?  Are there other preferable sites?

Comment: Whether asking for websites is on topic is determined by the algorithm RAND(), if you want to know how to ask those types of questions here, that is best suited for meta

Comment: https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diy

Comment: Hmmm...looking for suggestions how could I rephrase it so it was useful to the users of this exchange in particular nor meta or others

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo ham.stackexchange is only for amateur radio questions. So the `diy` tag there will only apply to homemade radios and radio accessories.

Comment: Radio usage is on topic here. Radio usage, and even technical radio details are on topic at ham.se since ham.se is specifically about radio use. Custom radios would be on topic at ham.se with the `diy` tag you identified. Other custom outdoor equipment, such as custom tents or custom sleeping gear or water filtration, would **not** be on topic at ham.se. @RodrigodeAzevedo

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo did you misread "wilderness technology" as "wireless technology?" Although radios are used in the wild, ham/amateur radio isn't a wilderness pursuit, it's a hobby.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo uh sorry, it seemed a strange thing to link.

Comment: @WeatherVane Other than radios, what other DIY technology can be used in the wild and is discussed on the SE network? Water purification may be on-topic at Chemistry SE, but I cannot think of many more possibilities.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo The one who asked the question (user "mmcc") should be the one to answer that as far as the question is concerned. In general though, I would say that there are a lot of other DIY technologies for outdoor use. Technology does not need to mean "electrical device." We do have some DIY questions here, such as this one for DIY alcohol stove tech: https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/19783/when-building-a-penny-stove-how-do-you-keep-the-cans-from-splitting

Answer (score 2):

Try /r/bushcraft on Reddit.  A lot of that is discussion of shelters, fires, and knives, but making and mods do come up.

Most outdoors people seem to separate their outdoor life from there life in civilization.  They expect to buy stuff that just works.

Other leads:

Some of the survivalist subreddits, and web forums have sections on long term stays where they have to fix/improvise stuff.

You may want to flesh out your question with a series of examples, or turn it into a series of more specific questions:

E.g.  "Where can I find good instructions on building a lightweight portable twig fired rocket stove"

"How can I easily make a waterproof shelter tarp?"

"how can I modify a backpack so that I can carry out a dead deer?"

"I ripped the sole off by boot.  How can I improvise footwear in the bush?"

Some of the homesteading/back to the land sites also do well.  Mother Earth News has lots of various how-to articles.

These two are not "the great outdoors" in the recreational sense, but more of a "I'm out in the weather all day every day" sense.